# "have to be moved" or "must be moved" or "must move"?

Tags: adverbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I have to” vs. “I must”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71001/i-have-to-vs-i-must)

Which of these is correct?

> The camera have to be moved sideways instead of rotate to track the scene.

or

> The camera must be moved sideways instead of rotate to track the scene.

or

> The camera must move sideways instead of rotate to track the scene.

Should these read “instead of rotate” or "instead of rotation"?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71001/i-have-to-vs-i-must and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41951/whats-the-difference-between-i-must-help-her-and-i-have-to-help-her

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only concentrate on the first part of the sentences, the second and third examples are correct, although the second sounds more natural to my ear. The first example would be correct if you changed it to "*The camera **has** to be moved...*"

The second half of the sentences is on the contrary not correct. In the first two examples you could change it to "*... instead of **being** rotated"*, whereas in the final example would be correct if it read "*...instead of **rotating** to track the scene*".

As for the differences in meaning, check the question previously asked which Carlo_R has linked.